# How to fix invalid column name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to update my table but this error keeps showing.

> Server Error in '/' Application. Invalid column name 'id'.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ( [Emp_Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, [FirstName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL, [LastName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL, [Date_Employed] DATE NOT NULL, [Monthly_Salary] FLOAT (53) NOT NULL, [SSSNum] INT NOT NULL, [depNo] INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Emp_Id] ASC) );
```

Code

```
//SELECTED ROW WILL FILL THE FORM INSIDE THE MODAL
protected void tableEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
  upId.Text = tableEmployee.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text.TrimEnd();
  upLname.Text = tableEmployee.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text.TrimEnd();
  upFname.Text = tableEmployee.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text.TrimEnd();
  UpDate.Text = tableEmployee.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text.TrimEnd();
  upSal.Text = tableEmployee.Rows[index].Cells[5].Text.TrimEnd();
  upSSS.Text = tableEmployee.Rows[index].Cells[6].Text.TrimEnd();
  upDept.Text = tableEmployee.Rows[index].Cells[7].Text.TrimEnd();

  btnUpdate_ServerClick(); 
}
```

Modal

```
protected void btnUpdate_ServerClick()
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "MyUpdateModal", "$('#UpdateModal').modal()",true);
}
```

Update

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string id=upId.Text;
  string fName=upFname.Text;
  string lName=upLname.Text;
  string date=UpDate.Text;
  string sal=upSal.Text;
  string sss=upSSS.Text;
  string dep=upDept.Text;

  string query = "UPDATE Employee set id=@Emp_Id, fName=@FirstName, lName=@LastName, date=@Date_Employed, sal=@Monthly_Salary, ss=@SSSNum, dep=@depNo where id=@Emp_Id";

   string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
   {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
     {
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_Id", id);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", fName);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lName);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Employed", date.Trim());
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monthly_Salary", sal);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSSNum", sss);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depNo", dep);
       cmd.Connection = con;
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();

      }
    }
       BindGrid();
       Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

If I try removing the variables and replace them with .Text, the same error would occur. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is the column in the database called "id"? And either way, why are you setting it again?

Comment: If possible show your sql column definition that would be easier to solve.

Comment: Here's the table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
    [Emp_Id]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Date_Employed]  DATE          NOT NULL,
    [Monthly_Salary] FLOAT (53)    NOT NULL,
    [SSSNum]         INT           NOT NULL,
    [depNo]          INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Emp_Id] ASC)
);

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Do NOT use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` uses the C# variable names, rather than the column names of the `CREATE TABLE` statement you provided.

Fix the SQL statement to

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET FirstName = @FirstName, 
    LastName = @LastName, 
    Date_Employed = @Date_Employed, 
    Monthly_Salary = @Monthly_Salary, 
    SSSNum = @SSSNum, 
    depNo = @depNo 
WHERE Emp_id = @Emp_Id
```

Also, you cannot update an `IDENTITY` column. (and don't need to, in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "UPDATE Employee set Emp_Id=@Emp_Id, fName=@FirstName, lName=@LastName, date=@Date_Employed, sal=@Monthly_Salary, ss=@SSSNum, dep=@depNo where Emp_Id=@Emp_Id";
```

Use Emp_Id not id if you don`t have an id